# Аналог функционала --service-ports из Docker в Kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

Появилась потребности пересесть на Kubernetes с просто работы с docker`ом.

При работе с Docker очень выручал параметр --service-ports.
`docker-compose run --rm --service-ports my_service`.
Это позволяло вести интерактивную отладку кода со всеми подключенными микросервисами в кластере.
То есть у меня есть приложение G, брокеры  W1 и W2,  и какой-нибудь ELS.
В такой среде с помощью `--service-ports` я мог запускать приложение G на локали, прежде установив точки остановы и вести интерактивный дебаг в терминале в нужном мне месте.

[здесь подробнее о параметре --service-ports](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/)

Сейчас только осваиваю  Kubernetes и не нахожу аналоги, чтобы запускать под в подобном режиме с возможностью, чтобы брейкпоинты отрабатывали(понятно что можно провалиться в под и схитрожопить оттуда, запустив там приложение вручную, - об этом есть статья) и была возможность дебаг вести в терминале. Как понимаю из документации docker, речь идёт о том, чтобы запустить сервис с сопоставлением портов между сервисом и другими контейнерами.
Это позволяет также не ребилдить образы, а отлаживать код в параллельном режиме.

Буду благодарен тому, кто подскажет есть ли такое вообще в Kubernetes и как реализовать.

Разработка ведётся на  **Python 3.X**

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/

Comment: Это не выглядит как об этой же теме. Если правильно понял по доке, речь о развёртывании пода и подключения к нему каких-то внешних сервисов. В моём кейсе все броккеры и эластик также являются подами - всё запущено на локали.

Если я запущу это всё у себя на локали, то я не получу тоже логирование джанги  в терминал вне пода + код изменяемый на локали никак не отразиться на работе пода без ребилда.

Comment: Я, наверно, не понимаю, что вам нужно. У вас противоречия, вот например, `все броккеры и эластик также являются подами - всё запущено на локали`, так запущено в k8s или на локальном хосте? `--service-ports` всего лишь мапит порты из контейнера наружу, т.е. делает их доступными с localhost. `kubectl expose` описанный по ссылке, делает то же только в k8s кластере.

Comment: Если нужно запустить приложение локально, а все зависимости в k8s, то `kubectl expose` - то что нужно. Или вы хотите в k8s запускать свое приложение, но присоединиться к его консоли? Тогда вам нужен https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_attach/

Comment: хм...кажется я кое-что понял...я проверю это вернусь с фидбэком